# Mocking django ORM to unit test queryset

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function that dynamically generates a queryset of users by creating a bunch of Q objects and ORing/ANDing them together in a .filter(). Its reasonably complicated and involves queries on multiple related models.

I'd like to write unit tests for the function. I could do this by creating user instances in the test database and checking that the function works against them. I would also have to create instances of all the related models. It seems like this will be a very slow test.

Is there some way of mocking the ORM that will allow me to test my function without having to use the database? After all I don't actually want to test djangos built in filter method.

Comment: Sounds like you just need an easy way to create the objects. Try [Model Mommy](http://model-mommy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you @noamk that does sound very useful if I decide to go down the path of creating all the instances in the test database. But I was interested to know if there was a way I could avoid touching the database at all